# PHPUnit Test assertions different after upgrade from 3.6.6 to 3.7.5

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, phpunit

A couple of days ago I upgraded my app from 3.6.6 to 3.7.5. Before I did the upgrade I ran all my tests which provided the following results:

**// Environment**
CakePHP Version: 3.6.6
PHPUnit Version: 6.5.14

**// Results**
Tests: 476, Assertions: 1927

**// Sublime Text 3 find with $this->assert**
1038 $this->assert's found.
Therefore: 1038 $this->assert found and 1927 assertions in results.

**// Controller Test**

```
use Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase;

class UsersControllerTest extends IntegrationTestCase
{
```

======================================================================

I created a new project with composer self-update && composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app app_name. 
I copied all the files over and implemented the changes documented in the migration guide.

I logged in and everything worked (Except for the middleware csrf token mismatch error but thats another issue.)

I ran my tests again and the following results where provided.

**// Environment**
CakePHP Version: 3.7.5
PHPUnit Version: 6.5.8

**// Results**
Tests: 497, Assertions: 1135

**// Sublime Text 3 find with $this->assert**
1059 $this->assert's found.
Therefore: 1059 $this->assert found and 1135 assertions in results.

**// Controller Test**

```
use Cake\TestSuite\TestCase;
use Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestTrait;

class UsersControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use IntegrationTestTrait;
```

======================================================================

I've double checked I copied everything over accurately and everything is as it should be apart from understanding
the test results.

I also used Sublime Text 3 to check that I hadn't called $this->assert 792 more times after my upgrade but this confirmed it's been called the correct amount of times taking into consideration I did 21 more tests.

The only differences I can see are:

1. In 3.6.6 IntegrationTestCase is used.
2. In 3.6.6 PHPUnit Version: 6.5.14 is used.
3. In 3.7.5 TestCase and IntegrationTestTrait is used.
4. In 3.7.5 PHPUnit Version: 6.5.8 is used.

======================================================================

**// Question:**

I'm hoping someone can help me understand why I can do 21 more tests but have 792 less assertions? Is it the use of TestCase and IntegrationTestTrait instead of IntegrationTestCase or the PHPUnit version difference or maybe something else?

Thanks. Z.

======================================================================

@ndm, thanks for the input.

I would like to follow your advice but the situation has changed. I got up this morning and tried to replicate the results from yesterday. My new 3.7.5 app test results were the same:

**// Environment**
CakePHP Version: 3.7.5
PHPUnit Version: 6.5.8

**// Results**
Tests: 497, Assertions: 1135

Then I loaded my old 3.6.6 app and ran the tests again but the PHPUnit version had changed and these were the results:

**// Environment**
CakePHP Version: 3.6.6
PHPUnit Version: 6.5.8

**// Results**
Tests: 497, Assertions: 1135

I thought I'd made a mistake yesterday and copied the wrong folder so I got my master backups out which hadn't been touched (All the way back to 19/01/19). I loaded 4 backups all on CakePHP version 3.6.6. All of them show these results.

**// Environment**
CakePHP Version: 3.6.6
PHPUnit Version: 6.5.8

**// Results**
Tests: 497, Assertions: 1135

So now I'm wondering where on earth is PHPUnit 6.5.14?

Since 19/01/19 I've run my tests on my CakePHP 3.6.6 apps about 50 times and when you run the test the cmd line always displays the PHPUnit version so I know I was using PHPUnit 6.5.14.

And now I'm wondering what could explain this? This also means I cannot replicate the results from yesterday.

Your advice has put my mind at rest, ie: it could be a lot of different things. Also I need to weigh up the time it would take me to isolate the reason against the benefits of knowing the reason.

For the moment I've decided to put this issue on my to do list seeing as it still does run all the tests and it could be as you mention "*Maybe some assertion methods provided by CakePHP changed so that they internally make less calls to PHPUnit assertion methods. Maybe PHPUnit wasn't calculating things incorrectly in earlier versions. Maybe something totally different, there could be lots of reasons*" and it's an unknown amount of time to get to the bottom of.

Hopefully within the next couple of months I can free up some time to get into it but for the moment I've filed it under "Sherlock Holmes and the case of the missing PHPUnit version". :)

Thanks again, Z.

Comment: Maybe some assertion methods provided by CakePHP changed so that they internally make less calls to PHPUnit assertion methods. Maybe PHPUnit wasn't calculating things incorrectly in earlier versions. Maybe something totally different, there could be lots of reasons, pretty hard for anyone here to tell. You could start with updating PHPUnit and CakePHP separately, and in patch version steps (ie `3.6.6` > `3.6.7` > `3.6.8` etc), to check when exactly the assertion count changes, and then check what exactly changed in between the two releases. Also use a copy of your original app, not a new one.